# php дать ответ и продолжить работать

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Можно ли в php вернуть ответ и продолжить работу в фоновом режиме.
Например:
отправляем ajax запрос на регистрацию нового пользователя, в пхп получаем данные, записываем в базу, отдаем ид пользователя в ajax, на клиенте идет автоматический вход в аккаунт, а php тем временем отправляет почту с ссылкой для подтверждения аккаунта, и еще что нибудь

Comment: Если хотите извращений, то можно. Но не проще ли в скрипте с авторизацией сразу же отправлять почту, если пользователь найден? Или делать 2-ой ajax на отправку почты

Comment: я думаю это не проблема. но есть много нюансов. я вижу это так , вы отправляете  асинхронный запрос, который выполняет цепочку. цепляет нужные вам модели по очереди, в это время ваш экземпляр с которым работает пользователь продолжает выполнять действия - если все успешно прошло, то возвращается данные пользователю в частности перезаписывается сессия и при обновлении и переходе - он уже будет авторизован. Но это костыль на асинхронных запросах. Мне кажется опытные пользователи предложат оптимальнее вариант

Answer (score 1):

Скорее нельзя чем можно.

Сервер вернёт response с id нового пользователя и текущий php-процесс на этом завершится.

Но, вы можете послать с клиента новый ajax после первого, который должен отправлять письмо. Или, лучше всего, ставить задачу в очередь (rabbitmq, kafka). Очередь процессить отдельными воркерами.